# Facebook: Graph API not able to get lead generation forms created for particular page

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/page-id/leadgen_forms?access_token=access_token
not able to get data of lead generation forms created for this page anyone any comment meanwhile i am making API on python

Getting this error response

{
"error": {
"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (leadgen_forms) on node type (Application)",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "A2khWnhkIxvEywUcRj-rGt4"
}
}

Comment: The error message indicates that your `page-id` is not actually a page ID, but an application id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be called like this finally i found this solution this question is pending on even Facebook forum since last one year.
https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/page_id/leadgen_forms?pretty=0&fields=leads_count,name,page,status,created_time,about,context_card,tracking_parameters&limit=25&access_token=access_token